# Automation test report issues with JENKINS/MAVEN/ECLIPSE

Tags: automation, browser-automation

I am facing issues while generating reports after successful build using maven in jenkins.

First, I have created java code into my local machine using eclipse.
Second, After creating the code I converted it to the Maven and completed all required setup of pom.xml file inside jenkins using Maven.
Third, I ran the script it gives me the success response.

Below, it is my maven success build result logs.

---

Started by user jenkin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestProject
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
Established TCP socket on 35275
[TestProject01] $ java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.12.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven1 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.27.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.12.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12.jar 35275
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/user/Documents/eclipse-workspace/TestProject01/pom.xml clean install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info

[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------< TestProject01:TestProject01 >-------------------

[INFO] Building TestProject01 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TestProject01 ---

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ TestProject01 ---
[INFO] Installing /home/user/Documents/eclipse-workspace/TestProject01/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/TestProject01/TestProject01/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestProject01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.MavenDependenciesRecorder$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/

[INFO]

---

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

---

[INFO] Total time:  2.821 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-05T19:09:16+05:30

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/user/Documents/eclipse-workspace/TestProject01/pom.xml to TestProject01/TestProject01/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestProject01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/home/user/Documents/eclipse-workspace/TestProject01/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestProject/home/user/Documents/eclipse-workspace/TestProject01/; will archive in a separate pass
channel stopped
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /home/user/Documents/eclipse-workspace/TestProject01/test-output to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
Finished: SUCCESS

---

Now, The issue is I do not know how can I check if all testcases covered with success. Here, HTML report been generated but it stays the same after every build success which creating lot of confusion.

Please help!!!!!!!!